# data.table lappy convert date from numeric yyyymmdd to date format

Tags: r, date, data.table, lapply

Given the following DT:

```
Date1 <- c(20210103, 20220805, 20191231)                       
Amount <- c(10,20,30)                     
Date2 <- c(20190101, 20180220, 20240930) 
dt_1 <- data.table(Date1, Amount, Date2) 
dt_1
```

I am trying to convert the numeric yyymmdd to date format:

```
date_cols <- c(Date1, Date2)
dt_1 <- dt_1[, (date_cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = date_cols]
```

can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `date_cols` should be defined as `c("Date1", "Date2")`
2. Since `date1` and `date2` are numbers, change them to character first before converting them to date. Additionally, you need to supply the format the dates are present in your data.

```
library(data.table)

date_cols <- c("Date1", "Date2")

dt_1[, (date_cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) as.Date(as.character(x), '%Y%m%d')), 
       .SDcols = date_cols]

#        Date1 Amount      Date2
#1: 2021-01-03     10 2019-01-01
#2: 2022-08-05     20 2018-02-20
#3: 2019-12-31     30 2024-09-30
```

Or you may also use `lubridate::ymd` which works without changing dates to characters and supplying the format explicitly.

```
dt_1[, (date_cols) := lapply(.SD, lubridate::ymd), .SDcols = date_cols]
```